# MySQL Proper Function

Tags: mysql, function

All,

I am posting two functions that I have built to clean text in MySQL, since I could not find online code for this in my research.

The first function properword() will convert a text string to lower case, bar the first word which is upper case.

The second function proper() uses properword() to convert a text string to lower case, bar the first letter following any full stop.

Please see the answer to this question below for the functions as described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- properword()
-- starts a sentence with an upper case letter, the remaining word is in lower case.

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS properword;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION properword( str text)
RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
DECLARE s Text;
DECLARE t Text;
SET s = UPPER(LEFT(str, 1));
SET t = LOWER(RIGHT(str, LENGTH(str)-1));
RETURN CONCAT(s,t);
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;

-- proper()
-- corrects a sentence so that the first letter after each full stop is a capital. Otherwise the words are in lower case

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS proper;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION proper(str text)
-- "hello. world. Thanks!"
RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN

DECLARE m Text;
DECLARE n Text;
DECLARE o Text;
DECLARE p Text;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE j INT DEFAULT 1;

SET m = properword(str);
-- m = "Hello. world. thanks!"
-- length(m) = 21
WHILE i <= LENGTH(m) DO
    BEGIN
SET i = LOCATE(".", str, j);
IF i > 0 THEN
-- 1. i = 6
-- 2. i = 13
SET n = LEFT(m, i+1);
-- 1. n= "Hello. "
-- 2. n = "Hello. World. "
SET p = UPPER(RIGHT(LEFT(m, i+2), 1));
-- 1. p = "W"
-- 2, p = "T"
SET o = RIGHT(m, length(m)-i-2);
-- 1. o = "orld. thanks!"
-- 2. o = "hanks!"
SET m = CONCAT(n,p,o);
-- 1. m = "Hello. World. thanks!"
-- 2. m = "Hello. World. Thanks!"
SET j = i + 1;
-- 1. i = 7
-- 2. j = 14
ELSE
SET i = LENGTH(m) + 1;
END IF;
END;
END WHILE;
RETURN m;
END;
$$
DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would think that the world’s most popular open source database, as MySQL like to call itself, would have a function for making items title case (where the first letter of every word is capitalized). Sadly it doesn’t.

This is the best solution i found Just create a stored procedure / function that will do the trick

```
mysql> 
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS properword;
SET GLOBAL  log_bin_trust_function_creators=TRUE;
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION proper( str VARCHAR(128) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(128)
BEGIN
DECLARE c CHAR(1);
DECLARE s VARCHAR(128);
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE bool INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE punct CHAR(17) DEFAULT ' ()[]{},.-_!@;:?/';
SET s = LCASE( str );
WHILE i <= LENGTH( str ) DO   
    BEGIN
SET c = SUBSTRING( s, i, 1 );
IF LOCATE( c, punct ) > 0 THEN
SET bool = 1;
ELSEIF bool=1 THEN
BEGIN
IF c >= 'a' AND c <= 'z' THEN
BEGIN
SET s = CONCAT(LEFT(s,i-1),UCASE(c),SUBSTRING(s,i+1));
SET bool = 0;
END;
ELSEIF c >= '0' AND c <= '9' THEN
SET bool = 0;
END IF;
END;
END IF;
SET i = i+1;
END;
END WHILE;
RETURN s;
END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```

then

```
update table set col = properword(col)
```

or

```
select properword( col ) as properCOl 
from table
```